# expo eject - android app not finding developer environment after

Tags: android, expo, react-native

I have got my expo project and I ran 'expo eject' to run it in the react-native CLI. It works on the iOS with some adjusting (thanks to the guys on GitHub) however I can't seem to get my android to work. It's saying

'Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.'

I have tried building a new react-native app (without using expo) and it works no problem.

To me the ejected project is not linking to the environment somewhere. I have tried updating android studio, going through the environment setup and update gradle (that caused more issues haha)

Has anybody else come across this please?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out the solution around this. Run these next steps soon after you do 'expo eject' (As it suggests in the console after eject runs)

Next steps

›  You may want to run npx @react-native-community/cli doctor to help install any tools that your app may need to run your native projects.

›  Download your Android keystore (if you're not sure if you need to, just run the command and see): expo fetch:android:keystoreNext steps